# Why are my jReddit jar files not being stored in the libs folder in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, jreddit

I'm trying to use the Reddit API wrapper 'jReddit' in my android project in Eclipse, and I have added the dependency to my pom for Maven:

[image: Maven dependencies in pom]

When I run maven and get the jars they are brought into my build path:

[image: My project build path]

My order/exports section (if that helps)

[image]

But in my project explorer the jar files are stored outside of the 'lib' folder:

[image: Explorer view]

So, I'm assuming, that is why my app crashes with the NoClassDefFoundError exception:

[image: Logcat]

Even though no warnings or errors are displayed prior to compilation. Does anyone know how to solve this? Any help is much appreciated.